# Add element to XML when not existing in child PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>

<product>
<a>product a</a>
<b>data</b>
<c>data</c>
</product>

<product>
<a>product b</a>
<c>data</c>
</product>

</products>
```

When child-element < B > is missing, i want to add it to the XML file. so the < product > ends up like this.No data has to be added, just the element.

```
<product>
<a>data</a>
<c>data</c>
<b></b>
</product>
```

can this be done with simplexml ?

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file("xml.xml", NULL, TRUE);
foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible. Here's an example of how to do it (assuming you're not worried about the order in which the child element occurs):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('xml.xml', NULL, TRUE);
foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {
    if (isset($child->b)) {
        continue;
    }
    $child->b = '';
}

// output to new file
$xml->asXML('xml2.xml');
```

You can also find [an online Demo](https://eval.in/57084) that contains all data:

```
<?php
/**
 * Add element to XML when not existing in child PHP
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/19562757/367456
 */

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<r><product><b>hello</b></product><product/><product/></r>');

foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {
    if (isset($child->b)) {
        continue;
    }
    $child->b = '';
}

$xml->asXML('php://output');
```

Program Output (beautified):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<r>
  <product>
    <b>hello</b>
  </product>
  <product>
    <b></b>
  </product>
  <product>
    <b></b>
  </product>
</r>
```

Comment: With a small adjustment this worked perfectly :)

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('kieskeurig.xml', NULL, TRUE);